# Set horizontal/vertical taskbar edge position from command line?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, command-line, taskbar

Is there a way to set which edge the taskbar is laid out on (either horizontally or vertically to the top, bottom, left and right borders of the screen) via the command line?

Workarounds (like forcing explorer to restart after a registry mod) are ok if necessary, but clean ways are preferred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The settings are stored at:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StuckRects2
```

You can `reg import` the ready-made .REG files available [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1066-taskbar-move-location-desktop-screen.html) or `reg add` the settings yourself and if required, `taskkill` explorer.exe and relaunch it.

You can also use a utility like [**TSTbarSet**](http://www.ctrl-alt-del.com.au/CAD_TSUtils.htm), which allows you easy command-line access to most Taskbar-related settings:

> TSTbarSet is a command-line utility to set common settings of the Windows Taskbar for individual user sessions and apply them immediately. Common settings include hiding the clock on the taskbar, hiding Taskbar itself, and setting the position of the taskbar within the user session.
>
> This utility was written for the purpose of allowing an administrator the ability to deploy common Windows Taskbar settings for multiple users. TSTbarSet allows these settings to be implemented at anytime during a users session without the need to logoff and logback on again.

Comment: +1 for TSTbarSet. Easy to set up and worked beautifully.